# Structure moved into a closure borrows a reference from outside

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to develop a pretty simple REST API in Rust, using [warp](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp) and [Rust Reverse Geocoder](https://github.com/ggcode1/rrgeo). I have the following code:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let loc = reverse_geocoder::Locations::from_memory();
    let geocoding = Arc::new(reverse_geocoder::ReverseGeocoder::new(&loc));

    let sample = warp::get()
        .and(warp::path("loc"))
        .map(move || format!("{}", geocoding.search((42.0, 42.0)).unwrap().record));

    warp::serve(sample)
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030))
        .await;
    Ok(())
}
```

The compiler complains about `loc` being borrowed but living not long enough. I understand why (the value is dropped at the end of the `main` function, but still referenced in the closure), but I cannot find a way to work around this.

[`ReverseGeocoder`](https://docs.rs/reverse_geocoder/2.0.0/reverse_geocoder/struct.ReverseGeocoder.html) borrows from the `Locations` field, and is not `Clone`, so I wrap it inside an `Arc` to move it properly. There is no way for me to make `ReverseGeocoder` own `Locations`.

My question is pretty simple: how can I make `loc` live long enough to make this code compile?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about putting `loc` in a static using [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell)? I.e. `static LOC: Lazy<Locations> = Lazy::new(Locations::from_memory)`. Then you can get a static reference with `&*LOC`.

Comment: If `loc` is created only once, you could [leak](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) it, which should make it `'static` and therefore live long enough: `let loc = Box::leak(Box::new(reverse_geocoder::Locations::from_memory())); let geocoding = Arc::new(reverse_geocoder::ReverseGeocoder::new(loc));`

Comment: In their warp example, they use `lazy_static` https://github.com/ggcode1/rrgeo/blob/master/warp/src/warp.rs

Answer (score 0):

The three solutions proposed in comments (`once_cell`, `Box::leak` and `lazy_static`) both work. Many thanks to the comments authors! I chose `lazy_static` at first, then I refactored and finally used another more performant crate ([rgeo](https://github.com/etrombly/rgeo)) which doen't need such a trick.

So the answer to my question is: the general solution here is to increase the lifetime of `loc`, making it `'static`.